# How can I Capitalize each word and remove all special characters and then combine all words in Excel?

Tags: excel

I have an Excel sheet with 500 values in column A. I am looking for a formula to Capitalize each word and remove all special characters and then combine all words.

Text in Column A: Vision, mission, values/text and approach

Desired Output: VisionMissionValuestTextAndApproach

Comment: Perhaps clarify your Excel version.

Comment: Also, when you say you have "Vision, mission, values/text and approach", is that all in a single cell? If not, can you clarify which parts are in which cells?

Comment: I am using office 365 and all the values are in A1 cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use REDUCE and LAMBDA and SUBSTITUTE:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(PROPER(REDUCE(A1,{",","/"},LAMBDA(a,b,SUBSTITUTE(a,b," "))))," ","")
```

Adding to the array any other characters needing removal.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for all your help. Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For Office 365 Insiders:

`=LET(ζ,{",","/"},SUBSTITUTE(CONCAT(PROPER(TEXTSPLIT(A1,ζ)))," ",""))`

The part

`{",","/"}`

should be defined so as to contain all special characters which could occur within the string. It can of course be replaced with a reference to a range of worksheet cells containing those characters.

Note that, if you are not using an English-language version of Excel, the separator within the above array constant may be different from the comma.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I get #NAME? with the formula contains unrecognized text error.

Comment: Did you read my first sentence about Office 365 Insiders?